# Need to print maximum value for random number generator

Tags: java

This is an assignment so please don't just give me the answer im trying to understand.

I need to use the command line to tell the program how many numbers to generate. Ex.

```
java RanNumGen 5
expected 94 16 12 56 21
```

The program does that i now need to have it print the maximun number generated which in the example is 94

Below is my code that give random numbers from 0 to 100 "n" number of times based off of command line input.

```
public class RanNumGen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int max = 100;
        int min = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int randomNumber = ((int)(Math.random() * (max - min))) + min;
            System.out.println(randomNumber);
        }
        
    }
}
```

I know that i need to establish Max And Min so that it knows what to print but i haven't been able to figure out how.

I have used `int maxNum = Math.max(maxNum, randomNumber)`  but gotten the error cannot find symbol.
I understand that i would than use `System.out.println(maxNum)` to get the maximum number.

```
public class RanNumGen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int max = 100;
        int min = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int randomNumber = ((int)(Math.random() * (max - min))) + min;
            int maxNum = Math.max(maxNum, randomNumber);
            System.out.println(randomNumber);
            System.out.println(maxNum);
        }
        
    }
}
```

The code above gives error

```
RanNUmGen.java:8: error: ';' expected
                        int maxNum = Math.max(maxNum, randomNumber)
                                                                   ^
1 error
```

```
C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\TESU Coursework\COS-111-OL009\Intro CS\Programs>javac RanNumGen.java
RanNumGen.java:8: error: variable maxNum might not have been initialized
                        int maxNum = Math.max(maxNum, randomNumber);
                                              ^
1 error
```

Comment: Please show the code that doesn't work.  There's no reason `Math.max()` would not work so it must be something else.

Comment: "*Any refrences to where to start looking would be appreciated.*" - [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Updated code to include what i tried and error

Comment: On the very first loop, what should  the max parameter `maxNum` be? It's not defined anywhere beforehand until **after** the right hand side of the assignment is evaluated

Comment: And your print statement should be after the loop if you want the overall max

Comment: @OneCricketeer I defined the maxNum beforehand and changed the printstatement to after the loop and it worked as intended thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to compute N random numbers and then find the max and the min between these?

If so, using the Math.max is the right approach but you first have to declare what maxNum is, otherwise the compiler will not find it. In particular you need a number either that is the first random number or the absolute minimum number that you'd come up with.

So either, get one random and generate `N-1` more

```
int maxNum = ((int)(Math.random() * (max - min))) + min;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
```

or initialize it before the loop

```
int maxNum = 0;
```

Comment: "*If I understand correctly...*" - We should ask for clarification in the comments instead of posting speculative answers.

Answer (score 0):

The following sample code includes a method that returns an array of random unique integers

The parameters of the method allow to indicate the length of the array and the upper bound of the random unique integers

The `main` methods obtains an array of random unique integers, prints it, sorts it, and then prints the value of the greatest integer in the array

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    // Returns an array of random unique integers 
    public static int[] getArrayOfRandomUniqueIntegers(int length, int bound) {
        HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Random random = new Random();
        while (hashSet.size() < length) {
            int i = random.nextInt(bound);
            if (!hashSet.contains(i)) {
                hashSet.add(i);
            }
        }
        return hashSet.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array = getArrayOfRandomUniqueIntegers(8, 75);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println(array[array.length - 1]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code below

```
    int maxNum = Math.max(maxNum, randomNumber);
```

passed a undeclared variable maxNum into the Math.max() function so that the error happened.

Although you have declared the variable as

```
    int maxNum
```

, maxNum at the right side of the assignment "=" is still undeclared from the compiler's perspective. In detail, declaration "int maxNum" will only happen after the assignment "=" is done. So if you put the variable maxNum at the right side of the assignment (before it is declared), it will cause error because you try to assign a undeclared variable to another variable.